# Which rxjs operator should I use to get values from an observable array to filter based on an object property

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6

I have been racking my brain for a couple of weeks now with this problem. I have typed observable array being returned via an http request. This the array output to the console. I am trying to grab each item and check the properties._hg_layer. [image]

An ngrx state selector is then assigned to Observable and then passed to a BehaviorSubject. This emits the array but won't let me get out the values inside of the array. I have tried every conceivable operator combination. I can't tell if my issue has to do with how the response is typed coming out of the service or how I am using the operators. It will not let me have access to the typed members of the array. IT's as if it doesn't know the properties of the array objects.
[image]

I have tried assigning the type of object on the subscription and I can't get that to work either.

[image]

Any insight or help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Our of curiosity, any reason your features source (in the third image) is subscribed, but isn't listing data in the subscribe function? I would have expected something like featureSource.subscribe((data) => {}). Notice the data as an argument.

Comment: Good Call but it makes no difference if data is called out there or not. I have another instance in my code with   'subscribe.((data) => {})'  and that doesn't work either.

Comment: So I see in one of the examples that you are using a pipe function, which leads me to believe that you are in fact working in the newer versions of rxjs. I would first check that you do get features to begin with. Just subscribe to featureSource, pass data through subscribe function and print it. If you get the data, then you can move on to constructing the rest of your logic. I am saying this, because it doesn't look like the access pattern with map function is correct at the moment.

Comment: You can also use pipe() instead of subscribe() and then use a tap function to print out the array as is first. then add map or whatever else that you want. I imagine that is how you started, which is why subscribe ended up not having data in function argument (it definitely needs it)

Comment: I have tried both of those and both work. it prints as expected. as the first screen shot illustrates with both pipe and subscribe.

Comment: Now I gotcha, so essentially you are having an issue just being able to iterate over the results

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.featureSource.subscribe((features) => {
   // iterate here
   features.map((feature) => console.log(feature.properties));

   // or good ol'
   for (const feature of features) {
      console.log(feature.properties);
   }
})
```

Also, need to keep in mind that your `take(2)` [will actually emit the features independently](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html), not as an array. If you were to continue to use that, the code snippet above will need to change to process the item (essentially just doing what you would do in a map).

Comment: I had tried this as well before but upon running your example I think I may have found a clue as to why it is not working. It is telling me that map is not available on '{}'...The original response coming back is an object...I am mapping the array from a sub array of the response so the observable still thinks its an object and therefore won't let me use any array operators on it.

Comment: Ah, you are referring to your take(2). The above example would work ONLY if you are passing the whole array, take(2) will pass items individually as separate events! So there you go :)

Comment: It was a little bit unclear to me where each piece fit together from initial question, but it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was getting the order of the mapping correct. I had to map the array in the initial map(). Then map the individual objects on the subscription.  I solved my problem with the following:

```
this.updatedLayers$.pipe(
  map((features: Feature[]) => features),
  )
  .subscribe(val => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      featureSubject.next(val.length);
      this.featureSource.next(val);
      console.log('feature data', val);
      val.map(feature => {
        console.log('type', feature.type);
        console.log('properties', feature.properties._hg_layer);
        });
      }, 500);
    });
```